# Gaussian Curvature of the half-plane only with the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S= \{(u,v): u \gt 0 \}$ the half-plane. And the metric

$$g=du^2+u^2dv^2$$

How to find the Gaussian curvature of S? I don't if there is sufficiently information to do this.

Comment: So what level course are you taking, what is your background, and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm attending an undergraduate course in Riemannian Geometry. My background is regular basic differential geometry, and Rienmannian metrics, moving frame. I tried to find the moving frame of S and aply the structural equations.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, so if you're using moving frames, start with $\omega_1=du$, $\omega_2=u\,dv$. Determine the connection form $\omega_{12}$ with $d\omega_1=\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_2$ and $d\omega_2=\omega_1\wedge\omega_{12}$. What do you get?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, an I got this: $\omega^{2}_{1}=dv$, and $ d\omega^{2}_{1}=0$, so $\omega^{1}_{3} \wedge \omega^{3}_{2} = 0$. And 

$$ \omega^{3}_{1}=a_{11}\omega^{1}+a_{12} \omega^{2}$$

$$\omega^{3}_{2}= a_{21} \omega^{1}+a_{22}\omega^{2}$$

And if we use the wedge product we will find 
$$a_{11}a_{22}-(a_{12})^2=0 $$ . So we conclude that $$K=0$$. I think it's correct. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: There is no $3$ here, as $S$ is not necessarily a surface in $\Bbb R^3$. Indeed, you should be using $K\omega^1\wedge\omega^2 = d\omega_1^2$ (depending on your sign conventions). So, having $\omega_1^2=0$, obviously $K=0$.

Comment: I didn't know this formula yet, thanks.

Comment: There is some book of this subject that you recommend?

Comment: What book is being used in your course?

Comment: The official bibliography is:
1. Cartan, H. Differential forms, Hermann, 1970.

2. do Carmo, M. P. Differential forms and applications, Springer-Verlag, 1994.

3. Chern, S. Introduction to Differential Geometry, Notes of University of Berkeley,
Math. 140 Notes, 1969.

4. O'Neil, B. Elementary Differential Geometry, Academic Press, 1966.

5. Singer, I. M., Thorpe, J. A. Lecture notes on elementary topology and geometry,
Springer-Verlag, 1967.

Comment: You've got plenty of great sources there. If you want another, I have undergraduate [notes](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) you can look at. Section 3.3 gives a very quick summary of the differential forms approach.